# Rails 3 resource without prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a resource 'Post' in my app. The default routes for `resources :posts` gives urls like `/posts/:id`. Is it possible to remove 'posts' from the route, and just have `/:id` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `:path` to remove the '/posts' bit...

```
resources :posts, :path => "/"
```

Just be aware that this could confuse other routes which are defined below it in your routes file. It's best to have this kind of catch-all route at the bottom for this reason.

Comment: Ah, I just found answers saying 'path_prefix' => '/'. I guess it was changed to 'path' in Rails 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom route for this (make sure to put it at the bottom of your `routes.rb` file, otherwise it'll match non-posts routes too)

```
match ':id' => 'posts#show'
```